# What's the importance of lambda functions in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Can anyone explain to me the importance of the `lambda` function when creating interface with Tkinter?

I am building a super simple interface to get familiar with Tkinter and I wanted to make so that when I press the "Return" key on keyboard, it would have the same effect as dragging the mouse to the "Submit" button on the screen.

I had some problems with it because nothing seemed to work. That's what I was doing:

```
self.master.bind("<Return>", self.concluir_return)
```

Where `self.concluir_return` is the function responsible for making what I want after pressing the "Submit" button. But it was giving me a `TypeError`:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: concluir_return() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Which I don't understand at all, since only one argument was being given (`self`)

But all was solved when I looked into web and modified the line of code with the lambda function.

```
self.master.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.concluir_return())
```

It works perfectly, but I don't quite understand what is happening. I would appreciate if someone could explain.

Also, I hope this is not too generic of a question.

Comment: the `.bind()` method passes an additional argument: `event` (name what you want but that is the usual approach), this argument has to be handled, so either with lambda like you do (any name possible tho for example: `lambda e: self.concluir_return()`). You can handle it with lambda, it will return the function that expects one argument and it will get that one argument, alternatively if you want to use the first approach without lambda you could do sth like this: `def concluir_return(self, event=None):`

Comment: Lambdas are just anonymous functions, the problem is your method signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can anyone explain to me the importance of the lambda function when creating interface with Tkinter?

Arguably, they aren't important at all. They are just a tool, one of several that can be used when binding widgets to functions.

The problem with the binding in your question is due to the fact that when you use `bind` to bind an event to a function, tkinter will automatically pass an `event` object to that function you must define a function that accepts that object.

This is where `lambda` comes in. The command needs to be a *callable*. One form of a callable is simply a reference to a function such as the one you're using (eg: `command=self.concluir_return`). If you don't want to modify your function to accept the parameter you can use `lambda` to create an anonymous function -- a callable without a name.

So, for your specific case, you can define a lambda that accepts the argument, and then the lambda can call your function without the argument.

> But all was solved when I looked into web and modified the line of code with the lambda function.
>
> `self.master.bind("<Return>", lambda event: self.concluir_return())`

This works because the code is effectively the same as if you did this:

```
def i_dont_care_what_the_name_is(event):
    self.concluir_return()
self.master.bind("<Return>", i_dont_care_what_the_name_is)
```

As you can see, `lamda` isn't required, it's just a convenient tool that lets you create a simple function on the fly that calls another function.

Answer (score 1):

The `bind` method takes two arguments, `sequence` and `handler`, and will call `f(event)` when the specified event occurs.

In your case, `concluir_return` wasn't expecting any argument other than `self`, so your code raised an error when it was called with `event`.

The lambda function you used is the equivalent of:

```py
def f(event):
    return concluir_handler()
```

so it bypasses the problem by just ignoring the `event` argument.

Another way of doing this would be to add an argument to `concluir_return`.

Comment: The first argument for `bind` is actually called `sequence` but that's just something minor.